# What does "synchronized" mean in Java?

Tags: java, synchronized

I have been trying to learn design patterns. [This site](http://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html) uses the `synchronized` keyword, but I don't understand what it does.

I searched on the net and found that it is somewhat related to multi-threading and memory, but I am a mechanical engineer and don't understand what that means.

Can anybody please help me understand threads and the `synchronized` keyword?

Comment: `synchronized` is java specific keyword.

Comment: The code in the link is not C++.

Comment: The first point is that the code samples you've linked to are Java not C++.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no `synchronized` keyword in C++.

There is one in Java, though, where for methods [it means the following two things](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html):

> - It is not possible for two invocations of synchronized methods on the same object to interleave. When one thread is executing a synchronized method for an object, all other threads that invoke synchronized methods for the same object block (suspend execution) until the first thread is done with the object.
> - When a synchronized method exits, it automatically establishes a happens-before relationship with any subsequent invocation of a synchronized method for the same object. This guarantees that changes to the state of the object are visible to all threads.

[Similar rules apply to arbitrary blocks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dcl/index.html).

Also, I recommend learning from a peer-reviewed book, not some arbitrary non-authoritative website.

Answer (score 21):

In the (Java) example

```
public static synchronized Singleton getInstance()
```

means that only one thread at a time should be able to access the getInstance() method this to avoid a racing condition.

Answer (score 7):

As the commenters already pointed out, synchronized is a Java keyword.

It means that two threads cannot execute the method at the same time and the JVM takes care of enforcing that.

In C++, you will have to use some synchronization construct, like a critical section or a mutex. You can consult [this](http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf).